# sshd doesnt work (but started) in lxc (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, lxc

When I'm trying to connect with `ssh ubuntu@10.0.0.*` it fails with `Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer`, and I can connect to containers only with `lxc-attach -n (name)`.

How can I fix this?

**UPD 0:**

```
$ ssh -vvv ubuntu@10.0.0.243
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.243 [10.0.0.243] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/guava/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guava/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guava/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guava/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guava/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guava/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guava/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/guava/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.0.0.243" from file "/home/guava/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: What do your sshd logs say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add verbose svitch to ssd command for debug purposes:

```
ssh -vvv ubuntu@10.0.0.1
```

-v - stands for verbose, you can multiply options, the maximum cuont is 3

**UPD0**

Are permissions seted right?

```
sudo chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
sudo chmod 755 ~/.ssh
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

On remote host:

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
```

Is time is syncronized on both machines?

**UPD 1**

Can you put tail on remote mechine's auth.log?

```
tail -500 /var/log/auth.log | grep 'sshd'
```

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` log_level DEBUG/INFO:

```
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
```

Comment: I don't have any id_* file, and yes, permissions seted right

yes, it synchronized

thank you! i've found the error!

Comment: You are wellcome! In most cases the "Connection reset by peer" is a handshke error

Answer (score 0):

This is ages old, but no answer addresses LXC here.

If the host has sshd bound to 0.0.0.0:22, then the sshd on the host machine occupies all interfaces, and hence the sshd in the container cannot grab a free interface. The sshd on the host machine must be configured to **not** listen on all interfaces, so in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, the line

```
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

must be replaced by

```
ListenAddress 192.168.0.55
```

if the IP address of the network interface is 192.168.0.55 (change it to whatever the IP address of the network interface is).